# Node Red keep restarting on my raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, nodered

I deployed a flow to my node-red on the raspberry pi 3 and after that it keep restarting giving the following error:

```
22 Jun 17:26:21 - TypeError: client.subscribeToDeviceCommand is not a function
at Object.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/application/wiotp.js:208:24)
at DeviceClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/application/wiotp.js:51:42)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at DeviceClient.emit (events.js:185:7)
at MqttClient.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/ibmiotf/dist/clients/DeviceClient.js:109:19)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at MqttClient.emit (events.js:188:7)
at MqttClient._handleConnack (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:790:10)
at MqttClient._handlePacket (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:306:12)
at process (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:248:12)
at Writable.writable._write (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:258:5)
at doWrite (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:401:64)
at writeOrBuffer (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:390:5)
at Writable.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-contrib-ibm-watson-iot/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:317:11)
at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
nodered.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Unit nodered.service entered failed state.
nodered.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Stopping Node-RED graphical event wiring tool....
Starting Node-RED graphical event wiring tool....
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool..
```

and then keep restarting. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I searched the net. It seems that I created a flow with a node that is not fuly configured so I had to remove this flow. 
I was able to make node-red start again by renaming the flow file.

go to the folder

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $cd /home/pi/.node-red/
pi@raspberrypi:~/.node-red $ ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x  4 pi pi  4096 Jun 22 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 pi pi  4096 Jun 22 17:37 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 13283 Jun 21 18:03 .config.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi   100 Jun 22 16:46 flows_raspberrypi_cred.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi  3560 Jun 22 17:20 flows_raspberrypi.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi  3119 Jun 22 16:46 .flows_raspberrypi.json.backup
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi pi  4096 Apr 10 12:20 lib
drwxr-xr-x  4 pi pi  4096 Jun 21 17:59 node_modules
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi  9064 Jun 21 17:45 settings.js
```

I renamed the one with `flows_raspberrypi.json` and then started node-red and it works this time.